# Create EC2 Instance by Ansible Failed with ec2: error: unrecognized arguments:

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am newbie to Ansible and follow [this tutorial](https://djaodjin.com/blog/deploying-on-ec2-with-ansible.blog.html) to create a security group and an ec2 instance. The security group is created successfully, but creating ec2 instance is failed by ec2:

> error: unrecognized arguments:
>   /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-14244....

I did set up aws credentials and asnsible variables properly as below

```
# AWS Credentials
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx

# EC2 Environment Variables
export ANSIBLE_HOSTS=/etc/ansible/ec2.py
export EC2_INI_PATH=/etc/ansible/ec2.ini
```

The files and output are showed as follow. Any ideas for this issue? Thanks for your Help!

```
$ cat group_vars/all
# Variables listed here are applicable to all host groups 
key_name: sobrr-staging.pem
aws_region: cn-north-1
ami_id: ami-9e0c9ea7
instance_type: m1.small

$ cat basic-create.yml
# Basic provisioning example
- name: Create AWS resources
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: Create security group
    ec2_group:
      name: my-security-group
      description: "A Security group"
      region: "{{aws_region}}"
      rules:
        - proto: tcp
          type: ssh
          from_port: 22
          to_port: 22
          cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
      rules_egress:
        - proto: all
          type: all
          cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
    register: basic_firewall

  - name: debug basic_firewall
    debug: 'msg="{{ basic_firewall }}"'

  - name: create an EC2 instance
    local_action:
      module: ec2
      key_name: "{{key_name}}"
      region: "{{aws_region}}"
      group_id: "{{basic_firewall.group_id}}"
      instance_type: "{{instance_type}}"
      image: "{{ami_id}}"
      count: 1
      wait: yes
    register: basic_ec2

  - name: debug instance start
    debug: 'msg="{{ basic_ec2 }}"'
```

OUTPUT

```
ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts -vvvv basic-create.yml
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py:57: PowmInsecureWarning: Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.
  _warn("Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.", PowmInsecureWarning)

PLAY [Create AWS resources] ***************************************************

TASK: [Create security group] *************************************************
<localhost> region=cn-north-1 description=A Security group name=my-security-group
<localhost>
<localhost>
<localhost> u'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1424461765.15-98406246607462/ec2_group; rm -rf /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1424461765.15-98406246607462/ >/dev/null 2>&1']
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "group_id": "sg-63fae101"}

TASK: [debug basic_firewall] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "{'invocation': {'module_name': u'ec2_group', 'module_args': ''}, 'changed': False, 'group_id': 'sg-63fae101'}"
}

TASK: [create an EC2 instance] ************************************************
<127.0.0.1> instance_type=m1.small image=ami-9e0c9ea7 group_id=sg-63fae101 region=cn-north-1 key_name=sobrr-staging.pem
<127.0.0.1>
<127.0.0.1>
<127.0.0.1>
<127.0.0.1> u'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/env python /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1424461765.54-184834253412898/ec2 /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1424461765.54-184834253412898/arguments; rm -rf /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1424461765.54-184834253412898/ >/dev/null 2>&1']
failed: [localhost -> 127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
usage: ec2 [-h] [--list] [--host HOST] [--refresh-cache]
ec2: error: unrecognized arguments: /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1424461765.54-184834253412898/arguments


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/ec2-user/basic-create.retry

localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `key_name` parameter in `Ansible` ec2 module refers to the ssh public key you uploaded or created(if you want to reuse the previous key) in your AWS account. You may want to verify it matches the name you specified in the AWS account.

My guess is that the key name in you AWS account is `sobrr-staging`, not `sobrr-staging.pem`

Try use `sobrr-staging` and see how that goes.